# Determination of a phase shift function using wave equation

Tags: waves, vibrations

I have a question about solving for a phase-shift function. Suppose the function $$y(x,t) = A\cos(\omega t+\phi(x))$$ obeys/satisfies the wave equation $$\frac{\partial^{2}y}{\partial t^{2}} = c^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}y}{\partial x^{2}}$$ determine $\phi(x)$.

My attempt at this question was to find the second order partial derivative of $y(x,t)$ with respect to both variables $x$ and $t$ and insert them into the wave equation and solve for $\phi(x)$ but I got an odd-looking expression:

$$
\\-A\omega^{2}\cos(\omega t +\phi(x))=-Ac^{2}[(\phi'(x))^{2}\cos(\omega t + \phi(x))+\phi'’(x)\sin(\omega t + \phi(x))]\\
$$
My first thought was to cancel the function $y$ on the left-side by factoring $y$ from the right-side which would give:

$$
\omega^{2}=c^{2}((\phi’(x))^{2}+\phi’’(x)\tan(\omega t + \phi(x))) 
$$
And I don’t know where to start to be able to solve for $\phi(x)$ so I tried to constrain it by making the expression inside the tan function equal to $n\pi\\$, where $n=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ which would evaluate the $\tan$ function to zero leaving me with: 
$$
c^{2}(\phi’(x))^{2}=\omega^{2}\\ 
$$ which would be easy to solve, and the final expression for $$ \phi(x) = x\sqrt{\frac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}}}$$
And I have doubts the way I did it so can you please point me in the direction I should go or if there is a mistake I made somewhere!

Comment: Try $y(x,t)=\phi(x) T(t)$, insert this into the PDE and develop to separation of variables.

Comment: $y(x,t) = A\cos(\omega t+\phi(x))$ does NOT satisfy the wave equation. You've actually shown that yourself.

Comment: Solution to the wave equation: http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65532&page=17#pid451284

Comment: $y(x,t) = A\cos(\omega t+\phi(x))$ does not satisfy the PDE.

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I thought to, but I assumed the question to be true. Thanks.